# Changing the drop down icon color of jquery select element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to change the drop down icon color of jquery select element. It is highlighted in the below screen shot and below is the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

I am not able to control the icon color, although I can see some way to change the background color, but I want to change that icon color.

Please take a note from the code about jquery and jquery-mobile libraries I am using.

Anybody have any ideas on how to control this color?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />


<script src="../js/libs/jquery/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
                <select>
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                    <option>Option 4</option>
                </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Image:
[image]

---

CSS for arrow:

.ui-icon-carat-d:after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20style%3D%22fill%3A%23FFFFFF%3B%22%20points%3D%2211.949%2C3.404%207%2C8.354%202.05%2C3.404%20-0.071%2C5.525%207%2C12.596%2014.07%2C5.525%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}

Comment: could you replicate this on plunker/fiddle?

Comment: also, where is the icon in your code?

Comment: There is really no icon, if you use my HTML then you can reproduce the issue ..

Comment: you may need to override the css class of the icon,http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyRule/f7q8sp43/1/

Comment: @RandomChannel I do not have icon code, it is jquery mobile who is doing the stuff ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change styles in `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css`
namely some classes

```
// this is arrow
.ui-icon-carat-d:after

// this is rounded background behind arrow
.ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after, .ui-btn-icon-top:after, .ui-btn-icon-bottom:after, .ui-btn-icon-notext:after
```

Comment: Just curious, how you identified it ??

Comment: @hagrawal using chrome dev tool

Comment: I also tried that one but I couldn't see those classes .. I checked all styles .. I got these css classes ".ui-select .ui-btn" but how you figured out those one ??

Comment: Mate, I just used the HTML I provided in my question and then tried to use Chrome dev tool but I am not able to see those classes .. Reason I am asking is because not I want to color of the down arrow from white to blue .. Do you have any idea ??

Comment: I have got the CSS for arrow and updated it in my answer, but dnt know how that image is .. Can I replace it with my image? How can I change the arrow color ..